# Is there a systematic way to get elastic constants in pyiron?

Tags: pyiron

I would like to have the shear modulus and the Poisson's ratio of `Fe_C_Becquart_eam` with LAMMPS. Is there a job type which allows me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

At least currently there is no official elastic constants module in pyiron. We had an implementation of the ElaStic code http://exciting-code.org/elastic for pyiron but that one is still on the prototype stage. The challenging part is handling the different symmetries for the different structure geometries. If you are interested to develop an elastic constants module for pyiron it might be reasonable to start with the existing Murnaghan module https://github.com/pyiron/pyiron/blob/master/pyiron/atomistics/master/murnaghan.py#L304 .